# How to use URLConnection through a SOCKS proxy?

Tags: java, networking, socks

How can I set the `SOCKS` proxy for a `URLConnection` given by `(new URL(url)).openConnection()`?

Different proxies are needed on a per-connection basis, so please don't suggest setting system properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use different proxy settings on a per-connection bases, you can use the Java 6.0 `ProxySelector` mechanism as described in [Java Networking and Proxies](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).  Specifically, read sections 3 and 4.